# jung-visualization build fails

Tags: jung, jung2

I'm having an issue compiling the guava branch of jung found [here](https://github.com/jrtom/jung).  The jung-visualization's PluggableRenderContext.java has a compile error.  It appears this problem has come up before as visible by [this Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=jung+pluggablerendercontext+error), but the link redirects to the jung GitHub repository.

I've cloned the GitHub repository to my local machine and then imported a Maven project into eclipse.  When running with the goals "clean install" I get the following output when building jung-visualization.

---

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jung-visualization 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ jung-visualization ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jung-visualization ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/eric/Documents/Development/java/git/jung/jung/jung-visualization/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0:compile (default-compile) @ jung-visualization ---
Compiling 158 source files to /Users/eric/Documents/Development/java/git/jung/jung/jung-visualization/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] jung2 .............................................. SUCCESS [  0.570 s]
[INFO] jung-api ........................................... SUCCESS [  2.159 s]
[INFO] jung-graph-impl .................................... SUCCESS [  2.148 s]
[INFO] jung-algorithms .................................... SUCCESS [  4.028 s]
[INFO] jung-io ............................................ SUCCESS [  3.369 s]
[INFO] jung-visualization ................................. FAILURE [  1.770 s]
[INFO] jung-samples ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.192 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-16T23:59:57-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 62M/369M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0:compile (default-compile) on project jung-visualization: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/eric/Documents/Development/java/git/jung/jung/jung-visualization/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/PluggableRenderContext.java:[47,7] error: PluggableRenderContext is not abstract and does not override abstract method getEdgeShapeTransformer() in RenderContext
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] could not parse error message:   where V,E are type-variables:
[ERROR] V extends Object declared in class PluggableRenderContext
[ERROR] E extends Object declared in class PluggableRenderContext
[ERROR] /Users/eric/Documents/Development/java/git/jung/jung/jung-visualization/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/PluggableRenderContext.java:310: error: getEdgeShapeTransformer() in PluggableRenderContext cannot implement getEdgeShapeTransformer() in RenderContext
[ERROR] public Function<? super Context<Graph<V,E>,E>,Shape> getEdgeShapeTransformer() {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :jung-visualization
```

Any help would be appreciated! Best regards, MCG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a bug in the declaration of the Guava-fied RenderContext.java; instead of this:

```
Function<Context<Graph<V,E>,E>,Shape> getEdgeShapeTransformer();
```

it should be this:

```
Function<? super Context<Graph<V,E>,E>,Shape> getEdgeShapeTransformer();
```

so that the signatures are compatible.

Comment: Thanks Joshua.  Jung-visualization now compiles.   When compiling jung-samples, we get the following:  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0:compile (default-compile) on project jung-samples: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/eric/Documents/Development/java/git/jung/jung/jung/jung-samples/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/EdgeLabelDemo.java:[219,111] error: incompatible types: Function<CAP#1,Shape> cannot be converted to AbstractEdgeShapeTransformer<Integer,Number>

Comment: I imagine I've broken the EdgeLabelDemo sample, but commenting out lines 219-221 in EdgeLabelDemo.java allows jung-samples to compile.  A correct fix would be of course be better.

Comment: I did some refactoring of the edge -> Shape related code and everything compiles now; the changes are updated in the guava branch of the Github JUNG repository.  Please LMK if you see any problems.  Thanks for the report.